# Problem on row Echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a $3\times 3$ matrix $$A =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & -1\\2&1&0\\ 3&0&1\\\end{bmatrix}.$$ I have to find nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $PA$ is in row reduced Echelon form. 
I am not able to get any idea to solve this problem. I understand Echelon form of a matrix. But what exactly should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, the source you are reading should provide you with the procedure to calculate $P$ from the elementary row operations you are doing.

Comment: Hint: If you apply a row transformation on A that is equivalent to left multiplying A by the corresponding elementary matrix (i.e. the matrix obtained by applying the same row transformation on the identity matrix.)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am trying to solve past year exam papers and I haven't read such type of problems before. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @mathscrazy "Source" = "either textbook or notes". Of course, exams do not contain explanations.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Dear sir, sorry for my ignorance but I didn't find such stuffs in my notes. If you could suggest how to solve this problem. It would be of gret help to me. Thanks

Comment: @Moo Then RHS will be the inverse of A? Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain P in this way by left multiplication

$$P(I|A)=(P|PA)$$

thus consider $(I|A)$

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &2 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 &1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 &0 &1\end{array}\right]$$

and by row operations

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &2 & -1\\ -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-3 &2 \\ -3 & 0 & 1 & 0 &-6 &4\end{array}\right]$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &2 & -1\\ -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-3 &2 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 &0 &0\end{array}\right]$$

thus

$$P =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\-2&1&0\\ 1&-2&1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have one query. Whether the matrix $P$ is unique?

Comment: Didn't the question ask for row reduced echelon form (in which case $P$ will be unique) whereas you have solved for row echelon form (in which case $P$ is not unique)?

Comment: Note that since the third row of PA is a zero row, the third row of P can be every multiple of (1,-2,1),thus it is not unique for the given PA.

Comment: @gimusi Thank you very much. I understood now.